# laravel second join return query as null

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have this query

```
$products = DB::table('product_attributes')
        ->where('product_attributes.attribute_id', '=', $attri->id)
        ->joinoin('products', 'products.id', '=',
        ->get();
```

and it returns

```
Collection {#2788 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#2785 ▶}
    1 => {#2786 ▶}
  ]
}
```

but then I don't have access to my products cover image, so I changed my query to:

```
$products = DB::table('product_attributes')
        ->where('product_attributes.attribute_id', '=', $attri->id)
        ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_attributes.product_id')
        ->join('covers', 'covers.imageable_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->get();
```

and it returns:

```
Collection {#2805 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

empty!

Again I changed my query to:

```
$products = DB::table('product_attributes')
        ->where('product_attributes.attribute_id', '=', $attri->id)
        ->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_attributes.product_id')
        ->leftJoin('covers', 'covers.imageable_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->get();
```

and it returns:

```
Collection {#2807 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#2804 ▶}
    1 => {#2805 ▶}
  ]
}
```

yet without having access to my covers (same as my first query).

## question

How can I have access to my products with all other models relations?

## More...

here is some of other relations to my product model

```
public function covers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cover::class, 'imageable_id');
    }

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'imageable_id');
    }

    public function options(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class, 'product_options', 'product_id', 'option_id');
    }

    public function attributes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes', 'product_id', 'attribute_id');
    }

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_categories', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the relationships set-up you could do it in the following way:

```
$products = Product::with(['covers','attributes'])->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attri) {
      $query->where('product_attributes.attribute_id', $attri->id);
})->get();
```

This way you get all your products which have an attribute with the given identifier and along with those products you will also retrieve the covers and attributes.

To access a cover or attribute in the first product for example you could do `$products->first()->covers`

Comment: thanks but this returns `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'attribute_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where exists (select * from `attributes` inner join `product_attributes` on `attributes`.`id` = `product_attributes`.`attribute_id` where `products`.`id` = `product_attributes`.`product_id` and `attribute_id` = 51))`

Comment: Try using `product_attributes.attribute_id` in the `whereHas`

Comment: `Call to undefined method App\Product::product_attributes()`

Comment: is that when you do `$query->where('product_attributes.attribute_id', $attri->id)` in the `whereHas` ?

Comment: `$products = Product::with(['covers','attributes'])->whereHas('product_attributes.attribute_id', function ($query) use ($attri) {
              $query->where('attribute_id', $attri->id);
        });`

Comment: No that's not right, try the code in my previous comment

Comment: OK, that doesn't return error either the results, when I dd the results it returns strange query instead of products.

Answer (score 0):

Init only main object

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
```

Use relations as object. Not use query-builder.

```
$product->covers();
$product->photos();
```

Comment: I'm using query builder because it's search result based on my attributes, otherwise my products come with covers by default.

Comment: Try this `$products = Product::with(['covers','attributes'])->where('attribute_id', $attri->id);`

Comment: this returns error because there is no `attribute_id` in products table, `attribute_id` is in `product_attributes` table

Comment: `$products = Product::with(['covers','attributes'])->attributes()->where('attribute_id', $attri->id); `

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::attributes()`

Comment: `$products = Product::with(['covers','attributes'])->findAll()->attributes()->where('attribute_id', $attri->id); `